# How do I go from one html page to another using onclick attribute in an html form

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code below and I would like to know what to type in the `onclick` attribute in the HTML form, so that I can go from one page to another.

```
<form class="login-container" action="/var/www/html/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
    Select Image<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()" class="imageupload" name="image" id="image" placeholder="Select Image"/>
    <br/>
    <img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview..."/>
    <br/>
    <input type="number" min="1" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/>
    <br/>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="40"placeholder="describe how you want the picture to be done"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick=" "/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean go from one page to another ?

Comment: When the button is clicked the form will be submitted and that in itself will take you to whatever page is returned by your `.../upload.php`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on submit button all will be post on **upload.php** here you insert your data into database table.
After successfully insertion of data write below code to redirect to another page which page you want to open on button click.

`header('location:page2.php');`